# Creating shared folder between two Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, shared-folders

I discovered today that I have two WSL installed on my computer (Windows 10): one for Ubuntu 18.01 (will call it WSL 18.01) and one for Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL 20.04). WSL 18.04 is the only one I have used so far but I would like to try Ubuntu 20 in the future. Both are wsl-1
In command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Zaida>wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04    Running         1
  Ubuntu          Running         1
```

I would like to copy the home folder from WSL 18.04 to WSL 20.04, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to follow this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815011/moving-files-between-different-wsl2-instances/65838203#65838203
and created the folder /mnt/wsl/share in WSL 18.04, changed the permissions to everyone with `sudo chmod ugo+rwx share` and copied my home files.

However, when I opened the other terminal (WSL 20.04), the /mnt/wsl doesn't exist. I created it there then but after closing and opening it, it is still empty, while in WSL 18.04, it contains my copied home folder files.

What else do I need to do to make that folder shared across both WSLs?

As a note, that folder also hosts the mount points of the 4 hard drives I have on my PC. I don't know if that could be affecting why it doesn't show in the other WSL:

Contents of `\mnt` in WSL 18.04:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── $RECYCLE.BIN
│   └── System Volume Information
├── b
│   ├── $RECYCLE.BIN
│   ├── Program Files
│   ├── System Volume Information
│   └── WindowsApps
├── c
│   ├── $Recycle.Bin
│   ├── Documents and Settings -> /mnt/c/Users
│   ├── Program Files (x86)
│   ├── System Volume Information
│   ├── Users
│   ├── Windows
│   └── temp
├── d
│   ├── $RECYCLE.BIN
│   └── System Volume Information
└── wsl  <------------------- POTENTIAL SHARED FOLDER ACROSS WSLs
    └── share
        ├── .bash_aliases
        ├── .bash_history
        ├── .bash_logout
        └── .bashrc
```

Thank you very much for any information and please let me know if you require any other details.

Comment: I have this issue and I don't have this issue.  In one directory, I used a link to the '/mnt/c' in Ubuntu 20.04.  For that case, I just have to link the 2nd Ubuntu 22.04 in order to share them.  However, I have other directories that this question helps with, but I will use /mnt/wsl.  The only caveat is that things like *.emacs* need to be edited due to different versions and handling of configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `/mnt/wsl` shared folder only works for WSL2 distributions.  Since you are using WSL1, that won't be an available option for you.  It's definitely the best option when using WSL2.

In your case, with two WSL1 distributions, I can provide several options, but one "recommendation":

- First, the recommendation.  Use the `wsl` command like `ssh` to pipe files from one distribution to the other.  If you've never seen this technique, it can be quite confusing (and yet, eventually, enlightening).  It's extremely quick and easy, since it's a one-liner, but it's difficult to grok and get just right.

  From Ubuntu 18.04:

  ```
  cd ~
  sudo tar -cvf - . | wsl.exe -u root -d Ubuntu -e tar -C /home/$USER -xvf -
  ```

  Note that I have tested that exact command on my system with two distributions.  The only word I changed in the commandline was my `testtest` distribution to your `Ubuntu` distribution.

  Breaking that down, it:

  - Creates (`tar -c`) an "archive" of all of the files in the current directory, but doesn't put them in a "file" on the drive.  Instead, the `tar -f -` (with the special hyphen at the end) means that it outputs the archive on standard output.
  - Pipes that standard output to the `wsl.exe` command, which we then use to specify (with `wsl.exe -d Ubuntu`) that we want it to address the other distribution.
  - Runs the `tar` command in the other distribution to "receive" the piped tarball on its standard input.
  - Uses `tar -C /home/$USER` to change to your home directory in "Ubuntu" before extracting the files.
  - Uses `-xvf -` (extract, verbose, "file", "from standard input") to extract the files into that directory.
  - We do this as root on both ends to preserve ownership and permissions, even if your user doesn't have full permissions to a particular file.
  - `sudo` on the Ubuntu 18.04 side for root access, but `wsl -u root` on the receiving end so that we don't need to type a password there.
- You can simplify this (at the expense of using disk space) by just `tar`'ing the contents of your home directory to one of the Windows drives.  All of those Windows drives will be available in both distributions.  You can then switch to the other distribution and `tar x` (extract) it.
- You could also simply use Windows File Explorer to navigate to the `\\wsl$\` directory and copy the files between the distributions, but this may lose some Linux ownership/permissions.

  Under Windows 10, each distribution will need to be running.  It seems (as of today's update, perhaps) that Windows 11 will now show *all* distributions and auto-start them as needed.

  Navigate to your home folder that you want to copy, select all files, and paste them into your home directory on the other distribution.
- It's also possible to set up one of the distributions as an SSH server and transfer the files using `scp`, `sftp`, `rsync`, pipes (like we did above), etc.  It's actually easier to set up SSH for WSL1 sessions than it is for WSL2.
- And I haven't done this, but I think it would be possible to `rsync` files through the `wsl` command as well.

---

Also:

> As a note, that folder also hosts the mount points of the 4 hard drives I have on my PC. I don't know if that could be affecting why it doesn't show in the other WSL:

Not really.  WSL automounts all Windows drives under `/mnt/<drive_letter>` when it starts up for convenience.  It doesn't impact the ability to share via WSL distributions in `/mnt`.  That's just more a limitation of WSL1.

Comment: I forgot to actually select and thank you for your answer, but thank you very much for it! I had no idea that it was possible to use wsl as a ssh-like command!

Comment: No worries, and thank you as well - Rep is nice, but the confirmation of knowing it helped is even better!

Comment: Amazing solution!